# Pell equation equal area

Tags: number-theory, area, pell-type-equations

Let $D \in \mathbb{N}$, not a square, and consider the Pell equation $x^2-Dy^2=1$. Let $\lbrace (x_n,y_n) \rbrace$ be the set of positive solutions of this equation in increasing order. Let $A_n$ be the area enclosed by the line segment between $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ and the part of the hyperbola $x^2-Dy^2=1$ between $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$.

I once heard that $A_n$ is independent of $n$. Is that true? If yes, does anyone know a proof or a source of a proof for this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We let $(x_0,y_0) = (1,0)$ the trivial solution, and $(x_1,y_1)$ the smallest nontrivial positive solution. Then we have $x_n + y_n\sqrt{D} = (x_1 + y_1\sqrt{D})^n$. In the plane, multiplication with $x + y\sqrt{D}$ corresponds to multiplication with the matrix

$$M(x,y) := \begin{pmatrix} x & Dy \\ y & x \end{pmatrix}.$$

Since by assumption $M(x_1,y_1)$ has determinant $1$, multiplication with $M(x_1,y_1)$ preserves area. With $M(x_1,y_1)\cdot \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} x_n \\ y_n\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} x_{n+1} \\ y_{n+1}\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ for all $n$, and the fact that multiplication with $M(x_1,y_1)$ preserves the hyperbola $\{(x,y) : x^2 - Dy^2 = 1\}$, the assertion follows, because multiplication with $M(x_1,y_1)$ maps the region bounded by the line segment from $(x_n,y_n)$ to $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ and the arc of the hyperbola between these points to the region bounded by the line segment and the arc of the hyperbola between $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ and $(x_{n+2},y_{n+2})$.